# Is it Possible to Edit Data Found in HTML Tables?

Tags: javascript, html-table

I haven't been able to find this out, but is there a recommended JavaScript library/plugin out there that allows for the user edit the data in a table, much like any sort of input? Or should I just create a table with text inputs in the table's `<td />` tags?

Comment: If I could select more than one answer to be the accepted answer, I would!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the fabulous Datatables jquery plugin in combination with its editable addon - See demo here: http://jquery-datatables-editable.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/index.html

Datatables - http://datatables.net/
The addon that adds editability to it - http://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-editable/

Answer (score 1):

Would this feature be what you are looking for?
http://itlivewire.com/tuts/jquery-dynamically-change-table-rows.html

Or if you want the client to be able to edit a table, this plugin might be more useful:
http://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-editable/

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in a solution without plugins, simply target the cells,

If you know the ID of the table:

```
document.getElementById("**tableID**")
  .getElementsByTagName("tr")[Row Number]
  .getElementsByTagName("td")[Cell Number];
```

Otherwise you'll need to choose the table from the index

```
document.getElementsByTagName("table")[Table Number]
  .getElementsByTagName("tr")[Row Number]
  .getElementsByTagName("td")[Cell Number];
```

For instance if there was a table with 2 rows and 2 columns and I wanted them all to have a number I would simply do:

```
var tableElm = document.getElementById("**tableID**") //table element
  .getElementsByTagName("tr")[0]  //row element
  .getElementsByTagName("td");  //individual cells

the table and row selection is now cached in tableElm
tableElm[0].innerHTML = "1";
tableElm[1].innerHTML = "2";
tableElm[2].innerHTML = "3";
tableElm[3].innerHTML = "4";
```

you don't even need the ".getElementsByTagName("tr")[0]" unless you have a reason to query the rows themselves. If you get rid of it, CELL NUMBER will include every cell of the table regardless of row.